# PHP uploads with 2Tb partition limit

Tags: php, file, storage, limit, partition

Using PHP/Apache and now face a problem on Ubuntu linux where my web application's uploads are nearly 2Tb in total.

Does anyone have any experience in programming their PHP uploads to use multiple partitions? Maybe filling-up the partitions in a round-robin method to effectively give more storage?

The SAN I use has over 20Tb of storage, but I'm effectively being limited to only 10% of this!

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will hand off to the OS to handle the details and report any errors.

I'm assuming the problem isn't that any one single file is bigger than 2TB. but that you have thousands of files that are taking up all the partition that your web-server is on.

If you need to use multiple partitions, you should split your uploads folder using something that will split nicely according to your requirements.

You might want to know where a file is without having to trawl the whole *uploads* tree

e.g. you could split by something like:
 - upload date /year/month,
 - starting letter of file or
 - round(user-id/100)

Then you can mount different partitions within uploads.
You could have a folder called *uploads* and within that you could mount other partitions

```
 mount /dev/sdb2 /var/www/html/myapp/uploads/2014   
 mount /dev/sdb3 /var/www/html/myapp/uploads/2015
```

Initially you might have to transfer files from your old location to those new partitions so that the older uploads will be available under the new scheme.

To php this is transparent, I have done similar things even with mounted smb shares. You'll have to make sure the right permissions/users are set up so that PHP can write to those folders.

Comment: I will give this a try soon - I like it. Just investigating if there are any operating system level tools or methods I could employ first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a chunked upload.
There are libraries that can handle it on the client side for you.

http://www.plupload.com/index.php

Comment: Nice idea but this scares me - what if one of the 2Tb paritions became corrupt. I guess I would loose all the files if they had been split and chunked across.

Comment: You're just asking for a problem if you're using this "idea" of yours in a mission critical application. You should use a service like S3 to store these large files IMHO or RAID these disks. -JH

Comment: Disks are RAID 6 already - it appears to be the file system's limitation.